# change shortcut for visual mode

Tags: tmux

I would like to change my .tmux.conf file to reflect the following change:

```
Ctrl+b "["   -> toggles visual mode
```

to

```
Ctrl+b "v"
```

is it possible? how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I press Ctrl-?, I see:
`bind-key          [ copy-mode`

(Note: I'm not sure where you got the phrase "visual mode", so I'm suspecting that you may have a different version of tmux than I do.  I suggest that rather than blindly copying my end results, that you check your tmux's online help to see what it says about the [ key, and follow the same process I did.)

So I created a ~/.tmux.conf file (which did not pre-exist), and put the following line in it (modifying the original to do what you wanted)...

`bind-key          v copy-mode`

Then, to have your changes take effect, do one of the following:

- Either quit every copy of tmux, so the server shuts down.  (Do not simply detach a session, and start a new session.  The old tmux server will still be running.)
- Or, update the server's configuration by pressing the command key (Ctrl-B  by default) and then typing...  `:source-file ~/.tmux.conf`

This affected every running copy of tmux, including a session I had detached earlier.